# Azure AD Authentication Reply Address Mismatch

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, adal

So, I followed the guide [here](http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/hosting-multiple-ssl-sites-in-azure-vms/) to set up multiple SSL sites on our Azure VM.

The site that I'm having the issue with is setup so that the Azure VM endpoint redirects external traffic to that endpoint on port 443 to port 442 internally.

Now, when I'm trying to authenticate against Azure AD, I'm getting this:

```
Error validating credentials. AADSTS50011: The reply address
'https://website.com:442' does not match the reply
address 'https://website.com' provided when
requesting Authorization code.
```

I can't figure out why the port is being attached to the reply URL in the auth request. If the port is 443, it doesn't attach port 443 to the URL.

In the Azure Management Portal, I have the reply URL set as `https://website.com`. I cannot set the reply URL to `https://website.com:442` because that URL isn't visible to external traffic.

If anyone has any insight on how to resolve this, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When I am making the call below I can set `uri` to a URL without the port. Before I updated it, it was calling `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)` for the URL, which includes the local port. I've changed it to build the URL differently for debug and release.

`AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
    code, uri, credential, graphResourceId
)`